# Product of symmetric positive definite matrix with eigenvector and an arbitrary vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a symmetric positive definite matrix $P$ with distinct eigenvalues. $v$ is one of the eigenvectors of $P$ and $y$ is an arbitrary vector of the same size as eigenvector.

Is it true to say $v^T P y \geq (v^TP)^2 +y^2$. Why or why not?

Comment: The RHS of the inequality does not make any sense. Do you mean $\|v^TP\|^2+\|y\|^2$ instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering $(v^TP\pm y)^2\ge 0$ we can see $-2v^TPy\le (v^TP)^2 + y^2$ and $2v^TPy\le (v^TP)^2 + y^2$, which yeilds $-\frac12((v^TP)^2 + y^2)\le v^TPy\le\frac12((v^TP)^2 + y^2)$, so $v^TPy$ can't be $\ge(v^TP)^2 + y^2$ unless the latter is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\0&2 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\\\end{bmatrix}$. Let $\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix} 1/10\\ 1/10\\\end{bmatrix}$. We test the hypothesis and see that we would need $ \frac{3}{10} \geq 5 + \frac{1}{50}$, but alas this is not true.